# highlight the scroll bars by default - vue js vue-custom-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using  [vue-custom-scrollbar](https://binaryify.github.io/vue-custom-scrollbar/en/#maxscrollbarlength-number) in my code for tables. I can see the scroll bars only when I hover the mouse over table, is there any way to make the scroll bars highlight by default?

[image]

Comment: I think using pure CSS rules is good instead of using a whole library

Comment: The library is already there, I am looking for the existing features

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the corresponding class style to show the scroll bar always.

Find  the styles [here](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar/blob/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css). Remove the `hidden` style for the class (I believe the class name is `.ps__rail-y`, please check it at line no `27`).